# SQLExecDirect gets hanged in deadlock situation

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I need a little help here related to SQL and ODBC.

So in my project, I am using this SQLExecDirect() API to fetch the records from MS SQL server through ODBC.
and I have two tables here.
Table_1 and Table_2 for these tables, I have 2 stored procedures.

**procedure test1**

```
ALTER procedure \[dbo\].\[test1\] @IDD INT
AS Begin
Begin Tran
Update Table_1 Set name = 'chanky'
from Table_1 with (NOLOCK) where id = @IDD
waitfor delay '00:01:00'
update Table_2 Set name = 'na'
from Table_2 with (NOLOCK) where id = @IDD
Commit Transaction
End
```

**procedure test2**

```
ALTER procedure \[dbo\].\[test2\] @IDD INT
As
Begin
Begin Tran
Update Table_2 Set name = 'rit'
from Table_2 with (NOLOCK) where id = @IDD
waitfor delay '00:01:00'
update Table_1 Set name = 'uit'
from Table_1 WITH (NOLOCK) where id = @IDD
Commit Transaction
End
```

To create a deadlock, I have run these 2 procedures parallelly.

But when I try to access data from Table_1 using SQlExecDirect() It gets hanged and will remain in hang state until the deadlock ends.

I am using ODBC 17 version for SQL Server 2017. Is there anything I need to add in the code prior to SQLExecDirect() or any alternatives for this API.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks...!!

I tried SQLExecDirect() API and I am expecting that this API should return error code or any exception when deadlock happens. It should not be in forever hang state .

Comment: Please show relevant code that you are using to call `SQLExecDirect`. I must say, `NOLOCK` on an `UPDATE` makes no sense and does not work, I assume this is only for testing?

Comment: It is UTTER NONSENSE to use the NOLOCK hint here. It is usually nonsense to use it generally. But your problem is clear - you update the tables in reverse order. It makes no sense to have two procedures do EXACTLY the same thing but in a different order. So don't use both procedures.

Comment: @SMor Seems OP is just doing this for testing to see if deadlock handling is working, and the issue is that it appears the deadlock is not being detected. Needs a [mcve]

Comment: @Charlieface Never assume.

Comment: How quickly are you expecting it to fail? The blocked process monitor only wakes up to look for blocks and deadlocks every five seconds [by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/blocked-process-threshold-server-configuration-option). You have a 1 minute delay between the table updates, so it shouldn't take longer than 1 minute and 5 seconds for a victim to be chosen and rolled back.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes it takes more than 1 min. but I want to roll back early because if I give 1 hour delay then it will wait for 1 hour to roll back. I am expecting it should roll back as soon as possible. It should not hang for such a long time.

Note: delay I have given just for creating deadlock scenario.